# loop through HashMap return value "null"

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

**I have a hashmap in java in which I store for test:**

```
HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

 //add elements to HashMap
 hmap.put("1", "AA");
 hmap.put("2", "BB");
 hmap.put("3", "CC");
 hmap.put("4", "DD");
```

**Then I want to group my key-values by pairs**

```
 for(String id1: hmap.keySet()) {
            Integer id2 = Integer.valueOf(id1)+1;
            while(id2 <= 4){
                String IDs = id1 + "/" + String.valueOf(id2);
                String Contents = hmap.get(id1) + "/" + hmap.get(String.valueOf(id2));
                System.out.println(IDs);
                System.out.println(Contents);
                id2++;
            }
        }
```

**But I obtain as a result:**

```
1/2
AA/null
1/3
AA/null
1/4
AA/null
2/3
BB/null
2/4
BB/null
3/4
CC/null
```

While I was hoping

```
1/2
AA/BB
1/3
AA/CC
...
```

The code I post is just for example. I have a HashMap with (ID, value) and I want to create a new HashMap with all pairs of ID (one time each) and pairs of value. But the hmap.get(String.valueOf(id2)) returns always a "null" value.

Can someone explain why the second value is null and what I can do to remediate?

Comment: what the output should look like?

Comment: Your HashMap is a Integer -> String mapping, why are you using String as key type in your code?

Comment: Your key type is Integer. You shouldn't have the String.valueOf(id2) because that's creating a string type, and there's no default way to convert that back to an integer for the lookup. Just do hmap.get(id2).

Comment: Sorry. Wrong copy my keys are string but they are 1 2 3 4

My output should be
1/2  AA/BB  and not 1/2  AA/null

Comment: Can you briefly explain what you trying to achieve with the code you posted?  Your question and code seems quite misleading.

Comment: I have a set of document with ID as keys and text as values. I want to create pairs of documents (only one time each pair) with ID1/ID2 as key and content1/content2 as value. The print is just to show the result of my code, in reality I create a new HashMap. My problem is that the 
    hmap.get(id2) 
doesnt return the value for id2 but null.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect, try this:

```
 for(int id1: hmap.keySet()) {
        Integer id2 = Integer.valueOf(id1)+1;
        while(id2 <= 4){
            String IDs = id1 + "/" + String.valueOf(id2);
            String Contents = hmap.get(id1) + "/" + hmap.get(id2);
            System.out.println(IDs);
            System.out.println(Contents);
            id2++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I made a mistake when I copy my code here my keys are of course string 1 2 3 4

Comment: Did you check my answer in your ide?

Comment: Yes I modifie my code to have integer as key and test your code but the hmap.get(id2) is always null. I relly can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but i guess it's something like this? This makes pairs of all your keys and your values.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    //add elements to HashMap
    hmap.put(1, "AA");
    hmap.put(2, "BB");
    hmap.put(3, "CC");
    hmap.put(4, "DD");

    for(Integer id1: hmap.keySet()) {
        for(Integer id2 : hmap.keySet()){
            String ids = id1 + "/" + id2;
            String contents = hmap.get(id1) + "/" + hmap.get(id2);

            System.out.println(ids);
            System.out.println(contents);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes it's what I want to do but hmap.get(id2) returns "null" each time and not the value associated with key id2

Comment: I obtain the following print, running the code above: 1/1
AA/AA
1/2
AA/BB
1/3
AA/CC
1/4
AA/DD
2/1
BB/AA
2/2
BB/BB
2/3
BB/CC
2/4
BB/DD
3/1
CC/AA
3/2
CC/BB
3/3
CC/CC
3/4
CC/DD
4/1
DD/AA
4/2
DD/BB
4/3
DD/CC
4/4
DD/DD

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. Know I'm sur this code was correct I was able to find my mistake above in my code. As I create my first Hashmap in a mapper of mapreduce, it only store one element and delete the others each time. So the error doesn't come From the bit of code I post here, the value where really "null".